# C programming: void * argument is it really pointer to anything, can I pass function pointer there

Tags: c, pointers

I consider how should I use `void *` correctly (I have some break from C language). As I remember `void *` is used to enable passing any argument to callback function. I know that it is ok to pass something like primitive types `int *`, const `char *` or even collection of values as `struct attributes *`.

I consider whether passing pointer to function as `void *` will be ok.

ex.

```
typedef void (*callback_t)(void *);
typedef void (*my_custom_callback_t)( /* list of params */ )

void someAPIFunction( /*... */, callback_t callback, void *callback_param);

void standard_callback(void *param) { 

       ((my_custom_callback_t) param) ( /* my params */ );
}
```

I consider whether having such types it will be correct to pass my_custom_callback as param to standard_callback?

```
void my_custom_callback(/* list of params */) { }

someAPIFunction( /*...*/, standard_callback, my_custom_callback);
```

Comment: I just tried it and it seemed to work - have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes it work but I don't know if it is correct ?

Comment: @ChrisTurner Trying things is not valid way to test legality of matters in language with a concept of *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: I belive like @user694733 write below that I will need struct wraper { } but it works and I am confused!

Comment: @user694733 showing that they've done some research before posting a question is good thing though

Comment: @MichałZiobro If you're writing code on an x86-based system, you can get away with a lot of things that you can't on other systems.  x86 systems pretty much allow you to treat any address as any type without restriction - and without much if any performance impact.  So, yes it "works", but if you tried that same code a different type of CPU your code would possibly fail.

Comment: It's quite common for API-style callback setups to take both an explicit function pointer and, separately, a void* 'data' argument.  This helps support OO langauges while remaining C-compatible.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Yes I am working with such API but I want to use both my standard callback and enable for additional custom callback for clients of my code

Comment: @ThingyWatsit - qsort() sends in int(*f)(void *, void *) as one of the arguments. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot pass function pointer as `void *`.

> #### 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 1. A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>      any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
>      compare equal to the original pointer.

and

> 8. A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
>      type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted
>      pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
>      the behavior is undefined.

Notice how there is no mention of possibility to mix object and function pointers. It may seem to work on some system, but it's undefined behaviour and not guaranteed to work.

However, you can create wrapper object and pass address of that:

```
struct wrapper {
    my_custom_callback_t func;
};

struct wrapper my_wrapper = { my_custom_callback };
someAPIFunction( /*...*/, standard_callback, &my_wrapper);
```

Or just pass pointer to function pointer (function pointer *variable* is object type):

```
my_custom_callback_t func = my_custom_callback;
someAPIFunction( /*...*/, standard_callback, &func);
```

Comment: Minor point, but I think wording such as "you cannot *safely* pass function pointer as `void *`" would be better as it would be more accurate.

Comment: While this is undefined behavior according to the C standard, it's required to work in a posix environment. Presumably to support dlsym which returns a void* pointing to a function. Persumably any windows compiler that wants to support GetProcAddress will mean this needs to "work" on any windows compiler too.

Comment: Where it maybe not work are 8-bit microcontroller and DSPs, in the most other cases this will work and a lot of software require this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Most platforms will in fact allow you to pass a function pointer as a void *, but it's not theoretically allowed. Code might have different pointers to data. You also cannot pass a const-qualified address to a void *.

Comment: This is in fact listed by the C standard as a common (non-standard) extension. J.5.7.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out already, this is not allowed in the general case and you will probably get a compiler warning. This is because there are platforms where function pointers are larger than data pointers.

The much more common case however is that the pointer sizes are indeed equal. Interfaces for accessing shared objects like `dlsym()` or `GetProcAddress()` actually rely on that.

So if you are sure that all your target platforms will use the same size for function pointers as for data pointers, you can make it explicit (so the compiler doesn't issue any warnings) by first casting to e.g. `uintptr_t`. The cast to and from an integer is allowed for all pointer types, and *as long as the integer is large enough to hold the pointer*, well-defined. `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be large enough for a data pointer, so if the function pointer is the same size, it's fine.